# Replace List of string into an existing string C#?

Tags: c#, list, replace, indexof

I Have a class and inside this class a `string` variable. I want to replace all the occurrences of specific words inside this variable with the `List<string>` of `string`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class HelloWorld
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add("Sunil");
    lst.Add("Sunil123");
    lst.Add("Sunil@123");
    string smsTemplate = "Dear {#var#},You have successfully register to online system please login to system by below credentials,User Name : {#var#}   Password : {#var#}  SunSoft, DeshlahreMiniGraden";
    string searchStr = "{#var#}";
}
```

So the output of this "smsTemplate" variable should be replaced with the list of strings provided. For example `"Sunil"` should be placed at the position of first `"{#var#}"`,`"Sunil123"` should be replaced at the position of second `"{#var#}"` and so on.

Comment: Can you do `smsTemplate = "Dear {0},You have successfully register to online system please login to system by below credentials,User Name : {1}   Password : {2}  SunSoft, DeshlahreMiniGraden"`? And then do `string.Format(smsTemplate, lst.ToArray())`

Comment: You so not need to use REPLACE.  Simply set the item in the list : lst[0] = "Dear {#var#},You have successfully register to online system please login to system by below credentials,User Name : {#var#}   Password : {#var#}  SunSoft, DeshlahreMiniGraden";

Comment: @jdweng You clearly haven't read the question again

Comment: Do you *have* to use `{#var#}`? You need to parse that template before you use it. There are pretty good template engines already. [Handlebars.net](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net) is pretty close to what you posted. Another, more powerful one is [Scriban](https://github.com/scriban/scriban), a port of Python's Jinja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in a quite straight-forward manner by splitting the `smsTemplate` on the `searchStr` and building a new string by appending the split parts from `smsTemplate` and each item in `lst` in an alternating manner. For instance:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

lst.Add("Sunil");
lst.Add("Sunil123");
lst.Add("Sunil@123");

string smsTemplate = "Dear {#var#},You have successfully register to online system please login to system by below credentials,User Name : {#var#}   Password : {#var#}  SunSoft, DeshlahreMiniGraden";
string searchStr = "{#var#}";

var templateParts = smsTemplate.Split(searchStr);

// In case the {#var#} count in smsTemplate differs from the lst count
var replacementCount = Math.Min(lst.Count, templateParts.Length - 1);

var builder = new StringBuilder(templateParts[0]);

for (var i = 0; i < replacementCount; i++)
{
    builder.Append(lst[i]);
    builder.Append(templateParts[i + 1]);
}

var sms = builder.ToString();
```

A fiddle is found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BAthX0).

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, this will replace each string one by one, but only the first occurence:

```
private string SequenceReplace(string template, string search,
    IEnumerable<string> replacements)
{
    var output = template;
    
    foreach (var replacement in replacements)
    {
        int position = output.IndexOf(search);
        if (position >= 0)
        {
            output = output.Substring(0, position) + 
                     replacement + 
                     output.Substring(position + search.Length);
        }
    }
    
    return output;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("Sunil");
lst.Add("Sunil123");
lst.Add("Sunil@123");
string smsTemplate = "<snipped>";

var result = SequenceReplace(smsTemplate, searchStr, last);
```

Comment: Side note: `output = $"{output[0..position]}{replacement}{output[position..]}"` is a compact alternative.

Comment: Side note: Technically, if `replacement` contains `search`, e.g. `searchStr = "{#var#}"`, `list[0] ="bla-bla-bla and {#var#}"` the routine stops working; the remedy is to start searching not from 0 - `position = output.IndexOf(search);` but `position = output.IndexOf(search, position + replacement.Length - search.Length);`

Comment: That's very allocatey

Answer (score 1):

It is an expensive operation in terms of memory, which will result in low perfomace. The best way to approach it, is to be certain with what SMS templates you have. Please checkout my solution for your problem:

```
public class Solution
{
    public string SmsTemplate1(string[] args)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, {0}. Your new passowrd is {1}", args[0], args[1]);
    }
    public string SmsTemplate2(string[] args)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, {0}. Here are you accout details:\nNew login: {1}\nNew password: {2}", args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not pass `args` to `string.Format`, rather than explicitly unpacking `args[0]`, args[1]`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

There is solution with `IndexOf`, let me provide direct `Regex.Replace`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

int count = 0;

var result = Regex.Replace(smsTemplate, Regex.Escape(searchStr), match => lst[count++]);
```

Here we search for `searchStr` - note `Regex.Escape` to escape all regex symbols like `{` and for each `match` we get its substitute

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ffqbho)

A better way is to use `Dictionary`, not `List`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
  { "name",     "Sunil"},
  { "mail",     "Sunil@SomeMail.com"},
  { "password", "SunilSecret"},
}
```

And then

```
string smsTemplate = "Dear {#mail#},You have successfully register to online system please login to system by below credentials,User Name : {#name#}   Password : {#password#}  SunSoft, DeshlahreMiniGraden";

var result = Regex.Replace(
    smsTemplate, 
  @"\{#\p{L}+#\}", 
    match => dict.TryGetValue(match.Value.Trim('{', '}', '#'), out  var value) 
      ? value 
      : match.Value);
```

Comment: I don't believe there's anything in the documentation which states that the `MatchEvaluator` has to be called for each match *in order*? (Although it is implied, I'll grant)

Comment: @canton7: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator-system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions) "If you specify RightToLeft for the options parameter, the search for matches begins at the end of the input string and moves left; otherwise, the search **begins at the start of the input string and moves right**." (**bold** is mine, Dmitry Bychenko)

Comment: The search begins at that side sure, but I don't see docs saying what order the `MatchEvaluator` is called in. The [Remarks here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) says "*The method is equivalent to calling the Regex.Matches(String, String) method and passing each Match object in the returned MatchCollection collection to the evaluator delegate.*", but again the order is implied, not stated

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Dictionary instead? Anyway, I'd recommend you modify the string to be replaced from

```
string smsTemplate = "Dear {#var#},You have successfully register to online system please login to system by below credentials,User Name : {#var#}   Password : {#var#}  SunSoft, DeshlahreMiniGraden";
```

To

```
string smsTemplate = "Dear {0},You have successfully register to online system please login to system by below credentials,User Name : {1}   Password : {2}  SunSoft, DeshlahreMiniGraden";
```

If your list of strings always has the same order (username first (index 0), then password (1), then email (2)) you can simply do:

```
string.Format(smsTemplate, lst.ElementAt(2), lst.ElementAt(0), lst.ElementAt(1));
```

An easier way would be to use a Dictionary. Something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> lst = new Dictionary<string, string>();
lst.Add("username","Sunil");
lst.Add("password", "Sunil123");
last.Add("email", "Sunil@123");
```

Then with the above changes in the string you can simply do:

```
string.Format(smsTemplate, lst["email"], lst["username"], lst.["password"]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maintaining a template without any indication of what is what is *very* difficult and easily leads to errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) to split the input string on the replace string, [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0) to merge the resulting array with the list of replacement strings, and [`String.Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-7.0) to combine the parts back to a new string:

```
private static string SequenceReplace(string input, string replace, 
    IEnumerable<string> replacements)
{
    return string.Concat(input.Split(replace).Zip(replacements)
        .Select(s => $"{s.Item1}{s.Item2}"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use an existing template library instead of implementing another one. Popular libraries are mature, performant and tested by multiple developers over the years. You'll be able to find docs, ready-made templates or guides for many popular scenarios.

One option, that's very close to what you described, is [Handebars.net](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net/tree/master), a .NET implementation of the popular [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) template engine. This allows you to create and compile the template once, then reuse it to generate text:

```
var source = @"
Dear {{user}}},
You have successfully register to online system please login to system by below credentials

User Name : {{name}}
Password : {{pass}}

SunSoft, DeshlahreMiniGraden";

var template = Handlebars.Compile(source);
```

The template can be used either with dictionaries, strongly-typed or dynamic objects eg :

```
var data = new {
    user = "...",
    name = "...",
    pass = "...."
};

var result = template(data);
```

or

```
var data = new Dictionary<string,object>{
    ["user"] = "...",
    ["name"] = "...",
    ["pass"] = "...."
};

var result = template(data);
```